# Unicode error when writing russian symbols to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, unicode

I want to write cyrillic symbols to csv file but I get unicode encode error. English symbols works perfect. I'm using Python 3.6.2.

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
>   1-6: ordinal not in range(128)

```
import csv


with open("test.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    hello = 'привет, мир!'
    csvfile.writerow([hello])
```

Comment: it looks like you are running script with python2, in py3 unicode is a default string representation which means you should be fine writing data to the csv file.

Comment: @TarasMatsyk my PyCharm is configured for python 3.6.2 interpretor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare the encoding of the file when you open it.  `newline=''` is also required per the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) documentation.

```
import csv

with open('test.csv','w',encoding='utf8',newline='') as csvfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    hello = 'привет, мир!'
    csvfile.writerow([hello])
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to encode the `hello` string before you write it to a file (csv). Otherwise Python is expecting you to input only `ascii` characters, in case of non-ascii characters, you may use `utf-8` encoding as:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv


with open("test.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    hello = u'привет, мир!' # Better way of declaring a unicode string literal
    csvfile.writerow([hello.encode("utf-8")])
```

Comment: I get `|b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82, \xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80!'|` in my csv file

Comment: @DamirShakenov try with some other text viewer such as sublime.

Comment: tried in VS Code, Atom, Excel 2016 - the same result

Comment: Maybe your system/editor is set to some codepage other than UTF-8. Some editors offer the possibility to change codepage of the displayed file. Does this give you some result?

Comment: Have you copy pasted the same code ? I tried this code on Python 2.7 and sublime editor and it works fine.

Comment: You may try out @Juergen suggestions as well.

Comment: @Juergen my editor is set to UTF-8, how could I see default encoding on mac OS?

Comment: @ZdaR yes, copy pasting gives the same result

Comment: OP is using Python 3.  Python 3 has much better support for non-ASCII in the csv module.  This answer is Python 2-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your file

```
   # encoding=utf8  
   --------------------------------------
   import sys  
   reload(sys)  
   sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly this code solves the issue?

Comment: It doesn't fix anything since the question is tagged `python-3.x` and Python 3's default encoding is already UTF-8.  On Python 2 this trick is used to change the default encoding of `ascii` and breaks other modules that rely on the default.  This is always bad advice.

Comment: OK, the question is marked as Python 3, but this solution actually solves the problem for Python 2.7 !
Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2 guys, use this instead of the normal "open" function:

```
import codecs
codecs.open(out_path, encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
```

This is equivalent of the following in Python 3:

```
open(out_path, 'w', encoding='utf8')
```